# Is it normal for set.seed() inside a loop to result in duplicates?

Tags: r, data.table, subset, resampling, random-seed

I need to extract several stratified subsets from a dataset. I find it helpful to first only generate row indices which I then use to subset the dataset for further analysis. I did the following:

```
#strata variable
a1 <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,5,5,5,5,5,5,6,6,7,7,7,7)
set.seed(9292)
#some values
a2 <- rnorm(24)

xdt <- as.data.table(cbind(a1, a2))
#total possibilities
prod(xdt[,.N,by=a1]$N)


idlist <- list()
for(i in 1:1000){
  set.seed(i)
  xdt2 <- xdt[, .SD[sample(.N, min(1,.N))], by = a1]
  #return the index
  idlist[[i]] <- which(xdt$a2%in%xdt2$a2)
}


#create a tabular format of the indices
#each row of the table is to be used to subset datasets for analysis 
idlist <- matrix(unlist(idlist), nrow = 7)
idlist <- t(idlist)
idlist <- as.data.table(idlist)
idlist <- unique(idlist)
```

When one row per strata is picked, there are approximately 2000 different subsets that can be extracted. When I run the above code, I find that some rows are dropped with the `unique` command. This is fine because the end result seems to be identical so far. I can just increase the total iterations to more than 1000 if I want to end up with 1000 unique indices. However, I was wondering whether this is normal? If the `set.seed` is changing in every iteration, shouldn't there be perfectly unique possibilities all along, especially when there are so many more total possibilities (2160, which is almost twice in this case)?

Or, am I making a mistake that is not obvious to me?

Comment: Random is not the same as guaranteed-unique. With or without `set.seed`, you have a non-zero change of duplicates.

Comment: You could generate the 2160 possibilities and randomly sample 1000 from that list without replacement. Of course your real data set may be much larger.

Comment: @r2evans thanks! That cleared up a few things for me.
@dcarlson Yes, that is what I have been doing. Just wanted to clarify this doubt regarding `set.seed`

Answer (score 0):

As explained in comments. Using set.seed does not guarantee randomness.